# How to Download Heroku on mac

Tags: heroku

I have been trying to download Heroku software to upload the rails app I made but every time I try to download it, it says it failed.
And what version of heroku should I be downloading?

Comment: Please show us how you're trying to download it.

Comment: I can't put an image to show you guys as it says Earn more than 10 reputation to post images.

Comment: @AnshDay Hey if you're low on rep you could always upload to [imgur.com](http://imgur.com) and I'm sure someone could transfer your image to the right place.

Comment: @AnshDay So are/were you trying to download something like the [Heroku Toolbelt](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/)? Or from your comment below are you trying to install Postgresql locally? Or were you trying to add a Postgres add-on to your Heroku app? Let us know and we can edit the title and/or help you more.

Comment: >`it failed` - Can you give us the exact error message? It could be a problem with your internet connection or various other things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku is a hosting service and there is nothing to download.  You can sign up at Heroku.com and there are instructions on the site for how to upload your app.

Comment: IM sorry guys I'm trying to download PostgreSQL can't get that fixed my bad sorry...

Comment: I agree with Matt - Ansh could have meant the [Heroku Toolbelt](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/)

Answer (score 3):

if you have installed `node` and `npm` already, try this

```
npm install -g heroku
```

if you're using Homebrew, try this

```
brew tap heroku/brew && brew install heroku
```

once the installation is done, issue this to verify whether you've successfully installed Heroku on your Mac

```
heroku --version
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up your local workstation with the Heroku command-line client and the Git revision control system by installing the Heroku Toolbelt. Check out this [link](https://toolbelt.herokuapp.com/) to download Heroku toolbelt.